# Dask - How to connect to running cluster scheduler and access 'total_occupancy'?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scheduler, dask

I use the following to create a local cluster from a Jupyter notebook :

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=24)
c = Client(cluster)
```

Is it possible to connect from another notebook when the kernel is occupied (compute operation) ?

My goal is to access to 'total_occupancy' for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @moshevi you can connect to the scheduler by providing the address.

```
client = Client("address-of-scheduler")
```

Then you can use the `client.run_on_scheduler` command to execute operations on the remote scheduler

```
client.run_on_scheduler(lambda dask_scheduler: dask_scheduler.total_occupancy)
```

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.Client.run_on_scheduler

Comment: Additional info: `"address-of-scheduler"` can be obtained e.g. through `cluster.scheduler._address`.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect to the running cluster:

```
c_diffrent_notebook = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')  # '127.0.0.1:8786' is the default
```

I would advice to explicitly specify the host in the original cluster and no rely on the default.

you can access the scheduler via the clients cluster:

```
c_diffrent_notebook.cluster.scheduler.total_occupancy
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm unable to access to "cluster.scheduler.total_occupancy"

Comment: Thanks. In my case, c_diffrent_notebook.cluster is None. 
(My scheduler and workers are launched inside a docker service)

Answer (score -1):

In a Jupyter Notebook environment where you may run a cell multiple times, I used the following:

```py
# Create a Dask Cluster if we don't have one
try:
    dask_client
except NameError:
    dask_client = Client(n_workers=12, threads_per_worker=1)
```

As it kept warning me, not failing that it would create a new cluster over the top of the old one, which was frustrating.